# bootstrap - keep div fixed on horizontal scroll scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some controls at the bottom of the div. I would like these controls to remain fixed when the user scrolls.

[image]

I tried:
1) Making the div fixed. The problem with that is that id destroys my bootstrap attributes and also because the height is generated dynamically.

```
   <div id="timelineContainer">
  <p class="mes">{{mes1}}</p>
  <div id='chart_div' class="chart"></div>

  <div class="row fixedcontrols">

    <div class="fixed col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xs-1 form-group-lg">
      <button type="button" id="next1" class="btn btn-primary btn-block transback " ng-click="timeline.getPreviousData();"class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Load previous 100 records...">
        <span id="nextdata1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 ">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" class="tt" id="btn_ZoomIn" name="btn_ZoomIn" ng-click="timeline.zoomIn()"><span id="zoomin" class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3  form-group-lg">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="btn_ZoomOut" name ="btn_ZoomOut" ng-click="timeline.zoomOut()"> <span id="zoomout" class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-out"></span></button>
</div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 form-group-md ff">
    <button type="button" id="advanced1" ng-click="timeline.searchclick()" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Show Search</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xs-1 form-group-lg pull-right">
    <button type="button" id="next" class="btn btn-primary btn-block " ng-click="timeline.getNextData();"class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Load next 100 records..."> <span id="nextdata" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>



 #timelineContainer {

 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 white-space: nowrap;  border: 13px solid #bed5cd;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 background-color:  #5bc0de;
  }
```

Thank you.

Update:
The controls move when user scrolls as shown below. I want them to be fixed.

[image]

update: said picture
[image]

Comment: can you explain more?? what do you actually want to get

Comment: I want the controls to remain fixed when the user scrolls left or right. Currently, when I scroll, the controls scroll with and the user cannot see the control buttons.Please see my update.

Comment: do you have some more css ?? or js ?? which you forget to add here ??

Comment: Its alot of pages, I only pasted what I believed would be necessary to accomplish the said task. Tell me what you need and ill post it. Thank you.

Comment: Ok no problem you just want inner div which contain the control button .. scroll like a fixed navbar ..

Comment: Yes.that is correct Mostafa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125124/discussion-between-mostafa-baezid-and-vladimir999).

Answer (score 1):

What i can understand from your question is you want your div at the lower part of page to be fixed in position,

i hope a small change in css will solve your issue

```css
position: fixed !important;
```

if its not what you meant then can you please explain more !!

Comment: Yes, thats what I need, but the problem is that it messes up my bootstrap. I updated my question to show the results.

Answer (score 0):

set position of controls to absolute and make sure their ancestor is div with id timelineContainer. absolute will position the elements relative to its ancestor. no matter where you move they will be fixed to div.